# Query to count the top three items that appear multiple times

Tags: mysql, sql

In the query below I have a basic table with two fields `course_name` and `course_id`. I am trying to display through the query the top three courses by  the amount of times they appear in the table. I am using `COUNT`, then I am comparing the values in additional select to determine the top three and finally display the results by `GROUP by course_id`. I am getting a mysql syntax problem. How can I display the top three courses with the amount of times they appear in the table? [FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0400b3/1)

```
SELECT course_name, course_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM courses
JOIN (SELECT distinct cnt cnt3
 FROM courses
 ORDER BY cnt DESC
 LIMIT 2, 1) x
ON cnt >= cnt3
ORDER by cnt DESC
GROUP BY course_id
```

Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE courses
 (`course_name` varchar(15), `course_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO courses
    (`course_name`, `course_id`)
VALUES
    ('Math', 1),
    ('Science', 2),
    ('PHYS', 3),
    ('Study Hall', 4),
    ('History', 5),
    ('Social Studies', 6),
    ('Math', 1),
    ('PHYS', 3),
    ('Math', 1),
    ('Science', 2),
    ('Science', 2),
    ('Study Hall', 4),
    ('History', 5)
;
```

Desired Result:

```
+-------------+-------+
| Course_name | Count |
+-------------+-------+
| Math        |     3 |
| Science     |     3 |
| PHYS        |     2 |
| Study       |     2 |
| History     |     2 |
+-------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax error is due to this:

```
ON cnt >= cnt3
```

cnt is an alias and you can't use it in a join.  Also, your order by and group by clauses are in the wrong order.

**Edit starts here**

Looking at your query, you may have overengineered it.  Would this not give you your answer?

```
select course_name, course_id, count(*) records
from courses
group by course_name, course_id
having count(*) > 1
order by records desc    
limit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select course_name,cnt from(
Select course_id,course_name,count(course_id) as cnt group by course_id,course_name
)tmp 
Order by cnt desc limit 0,3
```